# Javascript - canvas - drawImage does not work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I have read all the other similar posts but I don't understand why it I have this problem.

I have a canvas (#canvas) and an image (hero.png) on the page, and a JS file loaded at the end of the body. In the JS code...

This works:

```
var game = {};
game.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
game.ctx = game.canvas.getContext("2d");
game.draw = function(){
  game.ctx.drawImage(game.hero, 200, 200);
}
game.hero = new Image();
game.hero.src = "hero.png";
game.hero.onload = game.draw;
```

And this doesn't work:

```
var game = {};
game.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
game.ctx = game.canvas.getContext("2d");
game.hero = new Image();
game.hero.src = "hero.png";
game.hero.onload = game.draw;
game.draw = function(){
  game.ctx.drawImage(game.hero, 200, 200);
}
```

Nothing appears. No error in the console. Why???

Thanks!

Comment: game.hero.onload is undefined, try changing the order. First define the draw function and then assign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call functions before define them only with this syntax:

```
function draw() 
{
  //COde here
}
```

By writting

```
game.draw = function(){};
```

You define a method to your object, you don't define a JavaScript function: that's why you can't call it before define it :)

Answer (score 1):

In your second hunk of code, you're defining

```
game.hero.onload = game.draw;
```

When game.draw is undefined, so your onload is undefined and nothing happens when the image is done loading.

Answer (score 1):

`game.draw` is not set when you assign it in your second example, you are copying an undefined value into `hero.onload`.

One workaround is to wrap the function you want to call in an anonymous function and call yours from there:

```
game.hero.onload = function(){ game.draw(); };
```

Have in mind that if `hero` loads before the definition of `game.draw` is finished, this code will fail.